# Deserializing JSON in Django

Tags: django, json, deserialization

This one has had me pulling out my hair. I've been trying to deserialize JSON in Django for the last couple hours.

I have a function:

```
    # in index.html
    function updateWidgetData(){  
        var items=[]; 
        for statement here:
            for statement here:
                var item={  
                    id: $j(this).attr('id'),  
                    collapsed: collapsed,  
                    order : i,  
                    column: columnId  
                };  
        items.push(item);  

        var sortorder={ items: items};  

        $j.post('2', 'data='+$j.toJSON(sortorder), function(response)
        {  
            if(response=="success")  
                $j("#console").html('<div class="success">Saved</div>').hide().fadeIn(1000);  
            setTimeout(function(){  
                $j('#console').fadeOut(1000);  
        }, 2000);  
    });

}
```

And I'm trying to deserialize the JSON in django:

```
# in views.py
if request.is_ajax():
    for item in serializers.deserialize("json", request.content):
        item = MyObject(id=id, collapsed=collapsed, order=order, column=column)
    return HttpResponse("success")
else:
    ....
```

And it hasn't been working. I know this is probably a really trivial question, but I've never used JSON before, and I'd really appreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: "And it hasn't been working" -- where is not working? Exploding in the Django view? A stacktrace/error message will help us to help you

Comment: The JS, upon success, shows a div called console that flashes the message "saved". It hasn't been showing up, making me assume that Django isn't sending the HttpResponse because of some error. I think that there isn't a django error page that pops up because it's ajax and it doesn't bring up another template.

Comment: You can use Firebug or Google Chrome developer tools to see the returned page (error page).

Comment: +1 for the title, easy to find.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`serializers.deserialize` is for deserializing a particular type of JSON - that is, data that was serialized from model instances using `serializers.serialize`. For your data, you just want the standard `simplejson` module.

And the second thing wrong is that your response isn't just JSON - it is an HTTP POST with JSON in the `data` field. So:

```
from django.utils import simplejson
data = simplejson.loads(request.POST['data'])
```

Comment: The error will be returned as a normal Django error page. Use Firebug to view it.

Comment: And, of course, it should be `request.POST['data']` (changed above).

Comment: Oh, whoops! Didn't catch that. Thanks a lot, I appreciate it!

Comment: [Since Django 1.5](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/#system-version-of-simplejson-no-longer-used) you'd rather use the [python `json` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json)

Comment: Django exposes POST data sent as 'application/json' in the field `request.body` - I'm not sure if this is a recent change or just because of the encoding.

Answer (score 5):

```
from django.core import serializers

obj_generator = serializers.json.Deserializer(request.POST['data'])

for obj in obj_generator:                          
    obj.save()
```

### Objects should now be saved and visible in django admin