# Trying to get and update or create model from json in Django

Tags: python, django

Im trying to get and update or create object in model from json list of dicts but i got an error btw my code is creating objects but cant update them:

"TypeError: Tried to update field authentication.CounterParty.GUID with a model instance, <CounterParty: CounterParty object (3)>. Use a value compatible with UUIDField.
"

models.py

```
class CounterParty(models.Model):
    GUID = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    contractor = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Counter Party'
```

tasks.py

```
def create_counter_party():
    response = [
        {
            "CounterpartyGUID": "e58ed763-928c-4155-bee9-fdbaaadc15f3",
            "CounterpartyName": "name1",
            "Customer": False,
            "Contractor": True
        },
        {
            "CounterpartyGUID": "123e4567-e89b-42d3-a456-556642440000",
            "CounterpartyName": "name2",
            "Customer": False,
            "Contractor": False
        },
    ]

    rep = response

    for item in rep:
        try:
            counter_party = CounterParty.objects.get(GUID=item['CounterpartyGUID'])
            updated_counter_party = CounterParty.objects.update(GUID=counter_party, name=item['CounterpartyName'],
                                                                customer=item['Customer'],
                                                                contractor=item['Contractor'])
            updated_counter_party.save()

        except CounterParty.DoesNotExist:
            counter_party = CounterParty.objects.create(GUID=item['CounterpartyGUID'], name=item['CounterpartyName'],
                                                        customer=item['Customer'], contractor=item['Contractor'])
            counter_party.save()
```

errors:

```
[2023-01-28 15:29:31,894: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-8] Task authentication.tasks.create_counter_party[a86333d9-e039-479e-8d35-37fa6b17dbfa] raised unexpected: TypeError('Tried to update field authentication.CounterParty.GUID with a model
 instance, <CounterParty: CounterParty object (3)>. Use a value compatible with UUIDField.')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zesshi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 451, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/zesshi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 734, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Shalltear/Desktop/Python/unica_django/authentication/tasks.py", line 27, in create_counter_party
    counter_party = CounterParty.objects.update(GUID=counter_party, name=item['CounterpartyName'],
  File "/home/zesshi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/zesshi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1191, in update
    rows = query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR)
  File "/home/zesshi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1822, in execute_sql
    cursor = super().execute_sql(result_type)
  File "/home/zesshi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1385, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "/home/zesshi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1782, in as_sql
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: Tried to update field authentication.CounterParty.GUID with a model instance, <CounterParty: CounterParty object (3)>. Use a value compatible with UUIDField.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserializing JSON in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390511/deserializing-json-in-django)

Comment: I don’t think so bcs this code can create object in models but can’t update them if something changed in json

Comment: [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/serialization/#) about serialization and deserialization, [custom serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35367650/django-custom-deserialization) example

Comment: Calling [update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once) is another misconception and it does not do what you think. It runs _sql update_ query without instantiating objects and returns _number of updated rows_, not object instances thus `updated_counter_party.save()` will never work. What you need is 1) deserialize objects 2) save them.

Comment: Calling `CounterParty.objects.create` and then `.save()` is another misunderstanding. `create` does perform saving to database and `save()` would attemp to save the same another time (save would happen twice). So the suggestion is to stop reinventing the wheel, read the docs and look at examples.